# Using SFML from C#

Tags: c#, sfml

ok, I went to the SFML official website, but there are no SFML tutorials in C#. There are only some for C++, which I do not know, and I do not know how to use that tutorial with C#

Answer (score 2):

If you download the [SMFL.Net](https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml.net/) distribution, you'll find documentation and examples within the archive. Translating the C++ tutorials into C# should be rather easy with that documentation.